# Exoplayer in recyclerview with images and video like instagram but stop only last video other still playing after backpressed in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer2.x

I tried all StackOverflow answers and youtube solutions but cannot found anything suitable that's why I post my question in it.

I want to make an app like Instagram which I show images and video but the issue is

1. when I swipe up in recycler view all video play automatically not only single shown screen.
2. when I back pressed the button then only the last video stop with audio other videos(audio) still playing in the background until kill the app.

What I want to do is.

1. single video play at a time which is shown on screen other video stores in cache like TikTok then after swipe I watch these videos.
2. after back pressed all video with audio stopped
3. onclicklistener with mute/unmute and double clicklistener.

here is my code...

Main Activity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;
Toolbar toolbar;
String JSON_URl = "https://wasisoft.com/dev/index.php";
List<newsFeedModel> feedModels = new ArrayList<>();
newsFeedAdapter imageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(mainBinding.getRoot());
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mews_feed_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("NewsFeed");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    showList();

}

void showList() {
    AndroidNetworking.get(JSON_URl)
            .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    // do anything with response
                    if (response != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                newsFeedModel FeedModel = new newsFeedModel();
                                FeedModel.setTitleName(object.getString("account_name"));
                                FeedModel.setLike(object.getString("likes"));
                                FeedModel.setDescrption(object.getString("media_type"));
                                FeedModel.setVideo(object.getString("media"));
                                FeedModel.setViewImg(object.getString("media"));
                                feedModels.add(FeedModel);
                                String res = object.getString("media");
                                Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: " + res);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        imageADD(feedModels);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "None ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    // handle error
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Value " + error.getErrorBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("TAG", "onError: " + error);
                }
            });
}

void imageADD(List<newsFeedModel> feedModel) {
    imageAdapter = new newsFeedAdapter(this, feedModel, this::videoPlayBack);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    manager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mainBinding.newsFeedRecycler.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    mainBinding.newsFeedRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mainBinding.newsFeedRecycler.setLayoutManager(manager);


}
void videoPlayBack(PlayerView player, Uri videoUrl,int position) {
    BandwidthMeter meter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelector track = new DefaultTrackSelector(
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(meter)
    );
    imageAdapter.exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, track);
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("video");
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUrl, factory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
    player.setPlayer(imageAdapter.exoPlayer);
    player.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    imageAdapter.exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    imageAdapter.exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.setUseController(true);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    imageAdapter.releasePlayer();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    imageAdapter.pausePlayer();
}
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class newsFeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
public static final int imageFeed = 0;
public static final int videoFeed = 1;
public SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
Context context;
videoCallBack callBack;
List<newsFeedModel> feedModels;
videoNewsFeed videoNews;
newsFeedModel model;
String Json_Url = "https://wasisoft.com/dev/";

public newsFeedAdapter(Context context, List<newsFeedModel> feedModels, videoCallBack callBack) {
    this.context = context;
    this.feedModels = feedModels;
    this.callBack = callBack;
}

public newsFeedAdapter() {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 0) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.images_news_feed, parent, false);
        return new imageNewsFeed(view);
    } else {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_news_feed, parent, false);
        return new videoNewsFeed(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == 0) {
        newsFeedModel feed = feedModels.get(position);
        imageNewsFeed imageNews = (imageNewsFeed) holder;

        Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(Json_Url + feed.getViewImg())
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageNews.viewPager);
        Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: " + feed.getViewImg());

        imageNews.title.setText(feed.getTitleName());
        imageNews.likes.setText(feed.getLike());
        imageNews.description.setText(feed.getDescription());

    } else {

        model = feedModels.get(position);
        videoNews = (videoNewsFeed) holder;
        videoNews.videoLikes.setText(model.getLike());
        videoNews.videoTitle.setText(model.getTitleName());
        videoNews.videoDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
        callBack.onSuccessPlay(videoNews.videoView, Uri.parse(Json_Url + model.getVideo()), position);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (feedModels.get(position).getDescription().contains("picture")) {
        return imageFeed;
    } else
        return videoFeed;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedModels.size();
}


public void releasePlayer() {
    if (exoPlayer != null) {
        videoNews.videoView.setPlayer(null);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        exoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
        exoPlayer.release();
        exoPlayer = null;
    }
}

public void pausePlayer() {
    if (exoPlayer != null) {
        videoNews.videoView.setPlayer(null);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        exoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
    }
}



public static class imageNewsFeed extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView dpImage, viewPager;
    TextView title, likes, description;

    public imageNewsFeed(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        dpImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_images_news_feed);
        viewPager = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_viewPage_news_feed);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_name_news_feed);
        likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_like_count_news_feed);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_comments_news_feed);
    }
}

public static class videoNewsFeed extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public PlayerView videoView;
    TextView videoTitle, videoLikes, videoDescription;

    public videoNewsFeed(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        videoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_video_exoplayer);
        videoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_video_name_news_feed);
        videoLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_video_like_count_news_feed);
        videoDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_video_comments_news_feed);
    }
    }
    }
```

videoFeed.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_image_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
    app:civ_border_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_name_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/profile_video_image_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_video_image_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/profile_video_image_news_feed" />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_video_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_video_image_news_feed">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/item_video_exoplayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:resize_mode="fill"
        app:show_buffering="when_playing"
        app:surface_type="texture_view" />

    <!--  <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/img_vol"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
          android:layout_margin="8dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_unmute" />-->
</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_like_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_video_video_news_feed"
    app:tint="@color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_message_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:rotation="290"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_message"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_video_like_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_video_video_news_feed" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_share_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_video_message_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_video_video_news_feed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_like_count_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:text="@string/profileCount"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/profile_video_like_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_video_like_news_feed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_like_text_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:text="@string/like"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/profile_video_name_comment_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_video_like_count_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/profile_video_like_count_news_feed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_name_comment_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/profile_video_like_count_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_video_like_count_news_feed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_video_comments_news_feed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:ems="19"
    android:justificationMode="inter_word"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="@string/dummy_text"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/profile_video_name_comment_news_feed"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/profile_video_name_comment_news_feed"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

From code, What I understand is that, when you click on the item, a callback comes in the video playback method. Here you are assigning

```
 imageAdapter.exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, track);
```

So every time, you click on the item, it will assign a new instance from the factory to `exoplayer` and when you back press, it will release only the last assigned exoplayer.

The previous instance are still active and playing.

So either releases the previous instance before assigning a new one or reuse the same instance.

```
void videoPlayBack(PlayerView player, Uri videoUrl,int position) {
    BandwidthMeter meter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelector track = new DefaultTrackSelector(
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(meter)
    );
    imageAdapter.releasePlayer();
    imageAdapter.exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, track);

    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("video");
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUrl, factory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
    player.setPlayer(imageAdapter.exoPlayer);
    player.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    imageAdapter.exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    imageAdapter.exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.setUseController(true);

}
```

Comment: i tried your solution now new issue is it can't play first video. and what other issue that i want to play only one video not all at a time.?

Comment: i never click on it it play automatically  as like instagram.

Comment: Can you share your project over Github, I have a project setup problem. I can debug easily

Comment: There is no such project... Can you push it to github

Comment: you can check it again..it 's privaye then  now it's public

Comment: have you found any issue?

Comment: will check @Adnanhaider. I will post

Comment: Kindly if you do both of my issues i am very thankful to you ...

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [github repo](https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin) with different module and what you're looking for is in one of them called [`rvItemPreview`](https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin/tree/master/rvitempreview) the preview by a longClick on the item but you can look at the project I forked it from https://github.com/mitchtabian/Video-Player-RecyclerView

Just so you know the issue you're having now is because you're creating a new instance of `Exoplayer` for each item which isn't a good for CPU management and other thing. You need to **create one instance of exoplayer** and attach it to item that is on the screen.

You're creating a new instance for each item in `onBindViewHolder` with `callBack.onSuccessPlay(videoNews.videoView, Uri.parse(Json_Url + model.getVideo()), position);`

Comment: this is in kotlin and how to implements it in java kindly explain about it.

Comment: and kindly also explain 2nd paragraph i dont understand how i create new instance of each item

Comment: this [link](https://github.com/mitchtabian/Video-Player-RecyclerView) is in java and shows how to do it, i've edit my post to give you more explanation

Comment: i am using this as an interface then i pass this in main class to use it..

Comment: Yeah and then in `videoPlayback(...)` you do `imageAdapter.exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, track);` so every item that calls this will create a new Exoplayer instance

Comment: how to solve this issue if i am using this way?

Comment: Have you looked at the link I gave you, https://github.com/mitchtabian/Video-Player-RecyclerView ?? there is also a video explaining everything

Comment: i watch this link its  a custom recyclerview which i dont want it..

Comment: why don't you want a custom recyclerview ? it's the only way you'll be able to have this behavior, I've searched a long time for this and it's the only way I've found

Comment: i did but i face another issue like , video is playing after 2 second video disappear and audio still playing and last video is playing middle video wont playing i dont know about this issue github.com/itsdani121/Wasigram  please check it if you understand whats problem